# batch file remove text before and after word

Tags: batch-file

i want to remove everything before `url=https://` and after `.ap.ngrok.io` mean I just want the code link `d045-113-172-146-154`

this is ngrok.log

```
t=2022-05-20T21:33:03+0700 lvl=info msg="no configuration paths supplied"
t=2022-05-20T21:33:03+0700 lvl=info msg="using configuration at default config path" path=C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local/ngrok/ngrok.yml
t=2022-05-20T21:33:03+0700 lvl=info msg="open config file" path=C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\ngrok\\ngrok.yml err=nil
t=2022-05-20T21:33:03+0700 lvl=info msg="starting web service" obj=web addr=199.0.0.1:4040
t=2022-05-20T21:33:03+0700 lvl=info msg="tunnel session started" obj=tunnels.session
t=2022-05-20T21:33:03+0700 lvl=info msg="client session established" obj=csess id=99dddre1f9ac
t=2022-05-20T21:33:03+0700 lvl=info msg="started tunnel" obj=tunnels name=command_line addr=http://localhost:80 url=https://d045-113-172-146-154.ap.ngrok.io
t=2022-05-20T21:33:18+0700 lvl=info msg="received stop request" obj=app stopReq="{err:<nil> restart:false}"
t=2022-05-20T21:33:18+0700 lvl=info msg="session closing" obj=tunnels.session err=nil
t=2022-05-20T21:33:18+0700 lvl=info msg="accept failed" obj=csess id=99dddre1f9ac err="reconnecting session closed"
```

I tried the code below but it print `echo is off.`

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "input=ngrok.log"
set "substr=https://"
(
    FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%G IN ("%input%") DO (
        set line=%%G
        set id=!line:%substr%=!
    )
)
echo %id% > yo.txt
set "substr2=.ap.ngrok.io"
(
    FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%G IN ("yo.txt") DO (
        set line=%%G
        set id2=!line:%substr2%=!
    )
)
echo %id2%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task getting the hostname from the single line containing the full URL can be done with the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if not exist "ngrok.log" exit /B 2
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "url=https://..*\.ap\.ngrok\.io" "ngrok.log"') do (
    set "Data=%%I"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "Data=!Data:*https://=!"
    set "Data=!Data:.ap.ngrok.io=|!"
    for /F "delims=|" %%J in ("!Data!") do (
        endlocal
        echo The hostname is: %%J
        set "HostName=%%J"
    )
)
if defined HostName echo The last hostname "%HostName%" can be used here, too.
endlocal
```

The command line with **FINDSTR** is executed in background using one more `cmd.exe` started with option `/c` and the command line within `'` appended as additional arguments. **FINDSTR** searches case-sensitive for lines containing a string matched by the regular expression `url=https://..*\.ap\.ngrok\.io` in the file `ngrok.log` in the current directory which of course can be any directory and must not be the directory containing the batch file.

The lines output by **FINDSTR** to handle **STDOUT** are captured by `cmd.exe` processing the batch file and processed by **FOR** after `findstr.exe` finished and the background command process closed itself.

**FOR** with `/F` ignores empty lines and by default also all lines of which first space/tab separated substring starts with a semicolon and assigns otherwise just the first space/tab separated substring of the line to the specified loop variable `I` for further processing it. That default line splitting behavior is not wanted here. Therefore an empty list of string delimiters and no end of line character is defined to get always each line with `url=https://` and `.ap.ngrok.io` assigned completely to the loop variable `I`.

The line is assigned next to the environment variable `Data` before enabling delayed expansion. Then delayed variable expansion is enabled as required for the next string operations.

There is first removed everything from the data line up to end of the first occurrence of `https://`. It is not possible to search for a string containing an equal sign because of `=` is interpreted as delimiter by command **SET** between search and replace string. The replace string is an empty string in this case.

There are next replaced all occurrences of case-insensitive interpreted search string `.ap.ngrok.io` by a vertical bar which no hostname can contain to mark the end of the hostname in the remaining data line.

One more **FOR /F** command is used to get the string left to the (first) vertical bar. It is expected that the string does not start with `;` as that would be a very unusual hostname. The hostname is output and also assigned to the environment variable `HostName` in the local environment defined with the second command line in the batch file.

If there is always just one hostname of interest in the log file, there could be used also the following code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if not exist "ngrok.log" exit /B 2
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "url=https://..*\.ap\.ngrok\.io" "ngrok.log"') do (
    set "Data=%%I"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "Data=!Data:*https://=!"
    set "Data=!Data:.ap.ngrok.io=|!"
    for /F "delims=|" %%J in ("!Data!") do (
        endlocal
        set "HostName=%%J"
        goto HaveName
    )
)
for %%I in ("ngrok.log") do echo ERROR: There is no hostname found in the log file: "%%~fI"
exit /B 1

:HaveName
echo Found the hostname "%HostName%" in the log file "ngrok.log".
rem Insert here more command lines for processing.
endlocal
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `cmd /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`